# java.lang.StackOverflowError ManyToMany: MapStruct - Spring Boot - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I'm doing an api rest on spring boot and I'm using MapStruct for the transformation between DTO's and Entities. The problem is that it launches an exception StackOverflowError in the relationship of ManyToMany. Could you help me?

Actor Entity

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Actor")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "films")
public class Actor implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "name is required")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    private Set<Film> films;
}
```

Film Entity

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity @Table(name = "Film")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "actors")
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Director_id")
    private Director director;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Actor_has_Film",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Film_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Actor_id"))
    private Set<Actor> actors;

    public void addActor(Actor actor) {
        this.actors.add(actor);
    }
}
```

ActorDTO

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActorDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;    
    private Set<FilmDTO> films;
}
```

FilmDTO

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FilmDTO {

    private Long id;
    private DirectorDTO director;    
    private Set<ActorDTO> actors;
}
```

DataMapper

```
public interface DataMapper<D, E> {
    E toEntity(D dto);
    D toDto(E entity);
    List<E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);
    List<D> toDto(List<E> entityList);
}
```

ActorMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface ActorMapper extends DataMapper<ActorDTO, Actor> {
}
```

FilmMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface FilmMapper extends DataMapper<FilmDTO, Film> {
}
```

FilmServices

```
@Service("filmServices")
public class FilmServices implements Services<FilmDTO> {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("filmRepository")
    private FilmRepository filmRepository;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("actorRepository")
    private ActorRepository actorRepository;

    private FilmMapper filmMapper;

    public FilmServices(FilmMapper filmMapper) {
        this.filmMapper = filmMapper;
    }

    public FilmDTO addActorToFilm(Long filmId, Long actoId) {
        Optional<Film> filmByIdOptional = filmRepository.findById(filmId);
        Optional<Actor> actorByIdOptional = actorRepository.findById(actoId);
        FilmDTO filmDtoWithNewActor = null;

        if (!filmByIdOptional.isPresent())
            throw new RuntimeException("The Film with id '" + filmId + "' does not exist");

        if (!actorByIdOptional.isPresent())
            throw new RuntimeException("The Actor with id '" + actoId + "' does not exist");

        Film film = filmByIdOptional.get();
        Actor actorToAdd = actorByIdOptional.get();

        boolean hasActorInFilm = film.getActors().stream()
            .anyMatch(actor -> actor.getName().equals(actorToAdd.getName()));

        if (!hasActorInFilm) {
            film.addActor(actorToAdd);
            Film filmWithNewActor = filmRepository.save(film);
            filmDtoWithNewActor = filmMapper.toDto(filmWithNewActor); // HERE THROW EXCEPTION
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("The Actor with id '" + actoId + "' already exist in the film");
        }

        return filmDtoWithNewActor;

    }
}
```

output logs:

```
Hibernate: select films0_.Actor_id as actor_id2_1_0_, films0_.Film_id as film_id1_1_0_, film1_.id as id1_3_1_, film1_.Director_id as director4_3_1_, director2_.id as id1_2_2_ from Actor_has_Film films0_ inner join Film film1_ on films0_.Film_id=film1_.id left outer join Director director2_ on film1_.Director_id=director2_.id where films0_.Actor_id=?
2020-04-07 15:27:26.296 ERROR 742 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at ar.com.ada.sb.relationship.model.mapper.FilmMapperImpl.actorSetToActorDTOSet(FilmMapperImpl.java:188) ~[classes/:na]
    at ar.com.ada.sb.relationship.model.mapper.FilmMapperImpl.toDto(FilmMapperImpl.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at ar.com.ada.sb.relationship.model.mapper.FilmMapperImpl.filmSetToFilmDTOSet(FilmMapperImpl.java:165) ~[classes/:na]
    at ar.com.ada.sb.relationship.model.mapper.FilmMapperImpl.actorToActorDTO(FilmMapperImpl.java:182) ~[classes/:na]
    at ar.com.ada.sb.relationship.model.mapper.FilmMapperImpl.actorSetToActorDTOSet(FilmMapperImpl.java:194) ~[classes/:na]
```

I would very much appreciate your help

Comment: N+1 query problem, check the log for query executed

Comment: When asking questions related to an exception, please always add the original exception message and the stacktrace!

Comment: added output logs @dpr

Comment: The problem is that you have a recursion in your data structures. ActorDTO hat a list of films and FilmDTO has a list of actors. I'm not much into lombok, so I can't give you a solution but maybe this hint will allow you to find a solution on your own.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's because of the recurrence issue between FilmDTO and ActorDTO, but that's the relationship between tables in the database. lombok doesn't participate in the cause of the exception, I just put it there so you can understand why the setter and getter annotations. When creating the getter, setter and constructors without lombok, it throws the same exception @dpr

Comment: I thought @Mapper would be a lombok annotation as well. Just noticed that it is MapStruct. Maybe look at this comment on github https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/469#issuecomment-249994986

Comment: the problem is that you have a cyclic dependency. There is an example in the MapStruct repo covering such case. Have a look at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles and see if this helps you.

Comment: Add @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class ... and change the definition of many to many to something like this @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.ALL
            },
            targetEntity= YourModel.class)

Comment: Thanks **Sjaak** and **dpr** no longer launch the exception applying the CycleAvoidingMappingContext, but there is still the circular dependency, I want when consulting films, bring me the actors without films and when consulting acts, bring me the actors without films. **Jailson Evora** not work for me

Comment: I guess the original problem now changed from a MapStruct problem into a resolving entities, right?  MapStruct generates codes. You can setup breakpoints in that generated code to see what going on. My suspicion is that @JailsonEvora is right and the remaining problem is  related to cascading. But its hard to gauge from your current code above. Can you help others by publishing the answer to your question (fixing the nullptr) so they befit from it? If problems remain, you can always open a new question with a minimum reproducer.

Comment: Ok @Sjaak, I will publish it soon...

Answer (score 0):

I stumble on this post and found a solution to the same problem of Circular dependencies or StackOverflowError with a @ManyToMany JPA relation using MapStruct.
The solution `@AfterMapping` proposed in [java.lang.StackOverflowError if Mappers have circular dependencies](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1163) didn't fit me for now.

Here I propose only a solution from Entity to Dto direction ie `List<D> toDto(List<E> entityList);`, the `List<E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);` elude me as not needed for moment but something to keep in mind would be the cascadable operations that are propagated to the associated entity such as PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface ActorMapper extends DataMapper<ActorDTO, Actor> {

  @Mapping(target = "films", source = "films", qualifiedByName = "filmIdSet") // circular dependencies
  ActorDTO toDto(Actor s);
  
  @Named("filmId")
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
  @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
  ActorDTO toDtoFilmId(Film film);
  
  @Named("filmIdSet")
  default Set<ActorDTO> toDtoFilmIdSet(Set<Film> films) {
      return films.stream().map(this::toDtoFilmId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
}


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface FilmMapper extends DataMapper<FilmDTO, Film> {

    @Mapping(target = "actors", source = "actors", qualifiedByName = "actorIdSet") // circular dependencies
  FilmDTO toDto(Film s);
  
  @Named("actorId")
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
  ActorDto toDtoActorId(Actor actor);
  
  @Named("actorIdSet")
  default Set<ActorDto> toDtoActorIdSet(Set<Actor> actors) {
      return actors.stream().map(this::toDtoActorId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
}
```

In a nutshell the idea is by default ignore all properties to avoid the circular reference and add only the non circular ones.

Another way is the following, but it gives less choice on what property we want to keep eventually

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface ActorMapper extends DataMapper<ActorDTO, Actor> {

  @Mapping(target = "films", source = "films", ignore = true) // circular dependencies
  ActorDTO toDto(Actor s);
  
}


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { })
public interface FilmMapper extends DataMapper<FilmDTO, Film> {

    @Mapping(target = "actors", source = "actors", ignore = true) // circular dependencies
  FilmDTO toDto(Film s);
  
}
```

I use Mapstruct Version: 1.5.2.Final

Answer (score -2):

Try this one, instantiate the HashSet<>() of both property and you need only one direction mapping, leave the actor side mapping commented.

Movie

```
@Entity @Table(name = "Film") 
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Film_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Director_id")
    private Director director;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.ALL
        },
        targetEntity= ActorModel.class
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "Actor_has_Film",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Film_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Actor_id") })
    @JsonProperty("actors")
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();

    public void addActor(Actor actor) {
      this.actors.add(actor);
    }
}
```

Actor

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Actor")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Actor implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Actor_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "name is required")
    private String name;

    /*@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Film> films = new HashSet<>();*/
}
```